# Access: the way the form is opened populates the combo box differently

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, auto-update

Not sure if this can be done:

Basically I have created a database which logs interventions for a client (i.e phone calls, appointments, documents etc etc) the current project workers log these interventions as they happen from their live caseload.  appointments have their own form, phone calls have their own form etc.

Now I have been asked to do the same for admin so they can log historical data for the last year or so, the thing is the selection  data of the combo box is different (ie. old staff, services we do not work with anymore)

Is it possible to have a form populate differently depending on how you open it, ie the admin way will populate all the historic selections, and the project worker (live way) will populate all today's relevant information? I don't want to have to duplicate loads of forms that basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy,
just change the source data for the combo box depending on who opens the form
use a variable or a checkbox or a UserID or something to tell who the user is then:

if varUser = 'boss' then
combobox.datasource = 'Select * from services where historical = 1'
else
combobox.datasource = 'Select * from services where historical = 0'
end

Comment: User ID is a great idea I do have Boss, Admin and PW already set up for other reasons but obviously not using it to its full potential, You probably guessed I'm learning as I go along :) thanks for the advise!